# Legacy EAR application fails on WLS14 because of AspectJ "event" pointcut

Tags: java, weblogic, aspectj

I have a legacy application that used to work on WebLogic Server 10, Java 6. Now, our customer requires us to migrate this enterprise application to WLS14. We don't have source code for the application, only the jars and plenties of customer libraries. We are allowed to inspect/decompile source as we like.

We have to perform this migration by moving the exploded EAR and its libraries to WLS14, and possibily update incompatible libraries.

So far, we have upgraded spring-core from 3.2.5 to 4.0.9, and added querydsl 2.0.9. Spring 3 didn't like Java 8 classes (package asm threw error...) and querydsl, to which application is compiled against, was not included in the runtime of WLS14.
We haven't upgraded any other library in order to minimize impact and risk of regressions.

We have then identified another dead point when starting WLS14. The application fails to deploy because of an AOP-related `IllegalArgumentException`, specifically

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut event
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
```

It took us hours to investigate, and we are here after no conclusion.

There is a customer-private Java module (`acme-aspect.jar`) that contains a class `MarshallAspect`, that doens't extend any particular superclass, with methods

```
@Before("event(notice) && !execution(* Object.*(..))")
public void enrich(JoinPoint jp, Notice notice) {
...
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.acme.notificator.dispatcher.business.NotificatorDispatcherServiceBusiness.marshall(com.acme.notificator.model.notice1.Notice)) && !within(MarshallAspect) && args(notice)")
public void event(Notice notice) {
    //empty
}
```

We are struggling to understand, without access to source code (but we can decompile anything!!) or original **knowledge**, why did the application work seamlessly on WLS10 and now on WLS14 complains for an invalid AspectJ expression.

What are we missing here?

Comment: Can you paste the whole exception?